# Java listener for MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, database, listener

I want to know if there is a way for a listener to tell a Java program that there is an change in a table, when I update or insert a record in it. Is this provided out of the box by MySQL? If not, how can I implement the same?

Also, I have come across suggestions to use a trigger, but I don't know how to invoke a java program from a MYSQL trigger.

Thank you

Comment: From what I have read, It is not possible to directly invoke Java programs from a trigger in MySQL, but according to the below answer, a user has written a library to help with this :

**http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61388/38296**

P.S : I have not tried this, if you do decide to try it, please share your experience.